# Jquery Instagram feed doesn't work only with my username

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, feed

got a problem on a website with a Jquery instagram feed who doesn't work only with my username since few days without any reason.

The Jquery plugin's working with any instagram acc (he fetch the last posts and render it on your website), now, it render any account but not mine. I got a blank page when using my @username (the same as few days when ok)

If i try with a private acc, i got a msg that tell me this account is private so this is not de pb. And there's no modification on the insta acc

this is my code

```
<div class="container"> 
<div id="instagram-feed-demo" class="instagram_feed"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Instagram-Photos-Without-API- 
instagramFeed/jquery.instagramFeed.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $.instagramFeed({
            'username': 'sensationvtt',
            'container': "#instagram-feed-demo",
            'display_profile': false,
            'display_biography': false,
            'display_gallery': true,
            'get_raw_json': false,
            'callback': null,
            'styling': true,
            'items': 36,
            'items_per_row': 6,
            'margin': 0.3
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<br></br>
<!-- partial -->
 <script src='https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Instagram-Photos-Without-API- 
 instagramFeed/jquery.instagramFeed.js'></script>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
```

if you replace "sensationvtt" with "github" or any other public account, you will see a working feed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not related to coding, although I recently supported a friend and the issue was that his account was private. If an account is private, public APIs can't fetch data (or, better, fetch empty data), not sure whether it's your case, but it's worth to mention that.

Comment: @briosheje Thanks but as mentioned, the acc isn't private and when an acc is i got a message "tis account is private"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your profile is age-restricted, which, similar to being set to private, won't work with this plugin.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/pe2f5nxz/). You'll notice I've added `'on_error': console.error` which is how I ascertained that your profile is age-restricted. The error message is:

> Instagram Feed: It looks like the profile you are trying to fetch is
> age restricted. See
> https://github.com/jsanahuja/InstagramFeed/issues/26

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            <div id="instagram-feed-demo"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Instagram-Photos-Without-API-instagramFeed/jquery.instagramFeed.js"></script>

        <script>
            (function($){
                $(window).on('load', function(){
                    $.instagramFeed({
                        'username': "sensationvtt",
                        'container': "#instagram-feed-demo",
                        'display_profile': false,
                        'display_biography': false,
                        'display_gallery': true,
                        'get_raw_json': false,
                        'max_tries': 8,
                        'callback': null,
                        'styling': true,
                        'items': 36,
                        'items_per_row': 6,
                        'margin': 0.3,
                        'lazy_load': true,
                        'on_error': console.error
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin used to work before Instagram added a layer of security. Our team override this plugin to have a work around with this issue.

Please check the plugin here:

https://github.com/reillo/jquery.instagramFeed

**And please read carefully the documentation.**